# Left/Top overflow with scrollbars

Tags: javascript, html, css, scrollbar, overflow

I am positioning my element inside container using `transform: tranxlate(x, y)` css property.

When I move element to right or bottom - scrollbars appeared because container has `overflow: auto;`. However if I move element to left or top - obviously scrollbars doesn't appear because overflow doesn't work that way.

Now I'm looking for some minimalistic approach with pure html/js/css to be able to scroll container keeping in mind that inner content may be moved randomly to any sides.

In short, I want scrollbar to appear if the yellow block goes beyond left edge, the same way it appears when it goes to right edge?

Here is a [Codepen example](https://codepen.io/vdenisenko-waverley/pen/ExjYgGX) which shows the problem.

```js
var btns = document.querySelectorAll('button');
var inner = document.querySelector('.inner');
var offset = 0;

btns[0].addEventListener('click', function() {
  offset -= 25;
  inner.style.transform = `translate(${offset}px, 0px)`;
});

btns[1].addEventListener('click', function() {
  offset += 25;
  inner.style.transform = `translate(${offset}px, 0px)`;
});
```

```css
button {
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: block;
}

.outer {
  outline: 1px dashed black;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: auto;
}

.inner {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<button>Move Left</button>
<button>Move Right</button>

<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner"></div>
</div>
```

[image: scrollbar appears] [image: scrollbar doesn't appears]

Comment: I did not understand, you want to always show the scrollbar or never show the scrollbar? What exactly is the issue here? Also, can you provide a runnable snippet here in the question and not in a site out of StackOverflow?

Comment: Your Ask isn't clear, but if the right side cross element you can implement a condition for avoid go right site or maximum right-site equal value

Comment: sorry I'm working on something bigger, so this is just very simplified example - that's why it may be not easy to understand. But imagine object that moves inside a canvas, and I need to show scrollbars if any of boundaries crossed.

Comment: So, in short, what is your issue? you don't need to explain your entire project, just the problem you are facing. If I understood correctly, you want the scrollbar to appear if the yellow block goes beyond left edge, the same way it appears when it goes to right edge?

Comment: yes @CalvinNunes exactly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe this help... consider that the offset scroll cannot be negative; you can only go from 0 to infinite(I think lol); then, you can move your element through left and top negative values but it does not enable you to scroll to. So, You can augment the width and height based on the user requirement and scroll the same value to the inverse direction of the user move it will show the effect that the scroll able to go these posions that right now is unavailable (negative scrolls). When you go back, you have to reverse the augment and when the augment is null then you move your element as need.

I expect that my explanation was successful; excuse me for my english...

```js
"use strcit";

var blank, container, yblock;

function bLeft() {
  if (yblock.offsetLeft <= 0) {
    blank.style.width = blank.offsetWidth + 16 + 'px';
    container.scrollTo(container.scrollLeft + 16, container.scrollTop);
  } else {
    yblock.style.left = `${yblock.offsetLeft - 16}px`;
  }
}

function bRight() {
  if (blank.offsetWidth > container.offsetWidth) {
    blank.style.width = blank.offsetWidth - 16 + 'px';
  } else {
    yblock.style.left = `${yblock.offsetLeft + 16}px`;
  }
}

function bUp() {
  if (yblock.offsetTop <= 0) {
    blank.style.height = blank.offsetHeight + 16 + 'px';
    container.scrollTo(container.scrollLeft, container.scrollTop + 16);
  } else {
    yblock.style.top = `${yblock.offsetTop - 16}px`;
  }
}

function bDown() {
  if (blank.offsetHeight > container.offsetHeight) {
    blank.style.height = blank.offsetHeight - 16 + 'px';
  } else {
    yblock.style.top = `${yblock.offsetTop + 16}px`;
  }
}

window.addEventListener("load", function() {
  blank = document.getElementById("blank");
  container = document.getElementById("container");
  yblock = document.getElementById("y-block");
  document.getElementById("left").addEventListener("click", bLeft);
  document.getElementById("right").addEventListener("click", bRight);
  document.getElementById("up").addEventListener("click", bUp);
  document.getElementById("down").addEventListener("click", bDown);
});
```

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 20em;
  height: 20em;
  border: dashed 0.2em black;
  overflow: auto;
}

.blank {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.y-block {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: yellow;
  width: 3em;
  height: 3em;
}
```

```html
<div class="container" id="container">
  <div class="blank" id="blank">
    <div class="y-block" id="y-block"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div>
  <input type="button" value="left" id="left">
  <input type="button" value="right" id="right">
  <input type="button" value="down" id="down">
  <input type="button" value="up" id="up">
</div>
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of moving the object left or up, increase the height/width of the parent container when those properties go below 0, and scroll the window by the offset.

This will give the appearance of the object moving off canvas whilst giving you scrollbars, however the object never actually goes beyond (0,0)

Comment: You can't be sure of it. If it was a serial voting then the system should reverse it in 48 hours. If not you can flag for moderator attention explaining the abuse. I don't recommend handling this in the comments.

Comment: Not 100% but his answer gets downvoted (not by me as my rep <125) and mine got accepted, 5 mins later a bunch of my old questions get downvotes.  Considering this was the only thing I'd done today, I'd quite happily bet a few hundred on it ;)

Comment: @DAustin that approach is interesting btw, I'm trying to make it work right now

Comment: Unfortunately with rep as low as mine, I can only call him out on it in my own post's comments

Comment: @Vytalyi - Yeah I was working on a fiddle for you but my day job got in the way.  You'll probably need a wrapping DIV for the inner element, and I couldn't find a working JS function for scrolling the DIV to the right position.  Will take another stab at it this afternoon and update my answer with a working example if I get a chance

Answer (score -1):

Here is a quick example of how you can achieve container horizontal scrolling, while moving the yellow box.

```js
 var btns = document.querySelectorAll('button');
        var inner = document.querySelector('.inner');
        var outer = document.querySelector('.outer');
        var offset = 0;
        
        btns[0].addEventListener('click', function() {
            offset -= 25;
            inner.style.transform = `translate(${offset}px, 0px)`;
            outer.scroll({
                left: outer.scrollLeft -= 25
            });
        });
        
        btns[1].addEventListener('click', function() {
            offset += 25;
            inner.style.transform = `translate(${offset}px, 0px)`;
            outer.scroll({
                left: outer.scrollLeft += 25
            });
        });
```

```css
button {
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: block;
  }
  
  .outer {
    outline: 1px dashed black;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    overflow: auto;
  }
  
  .inner {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: yellow;
  }
```

```html
    <button>Move Left</button>
    <button>Move Right</button>
    
    <div class="outer">
        <div class="inner"></div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thanks! I've noticed scrollbars doesn't appear if move to left

Comment: Ofcourse not, the overflow only works according to the defined direction, which is ltr(left to right) by default.

Comment: That is exactly what is OP's issue... OP is asking about the showing scrollbar when moving to left edge